# Validating XML document against XSD in Groovy when they are available at certain URLs

Tags: validation, url, groovy, xsd, schema

Can anybody help me with a snippet to validate an XML schema with an XSD when they are available at some URLs..

Comment: Can you give a more specific example or possible some code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 10):

You can do this (adapted from [the documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150317013942/http://groovy.codehaus.org/Validating+XML+with+a+W3C+XML+Schema), with xml and xsd urls found using google)

```
import javax.xml.XMLConstants
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory

xsdUrl = 'http://abbot.sourceforge.net/doc/abbot.xsd'
xmlUrl = 'http://abbot.sourceforge.net/src/example/SimpleApplet.xml'

new URL( xsdUrl ).withInputStream { xsd ->
  new URL( xmlUrl ).withInputStream { xml ->
    SchemaFactory.newInstance( XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI )
                 .newSchema( new StreamSource( xsd ) )
                 .newValidator()
                 .validate( new StreamSource( xml ) )

  }
}
```